# Error while installing nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, npm, development-environment

Every time I install nodejs it shows Warning 1909 with a message-"Could not create Shortcut Node.js command prompt.lnk" ..Please tell me how to resolve it.
I have Windows 7(32 bit)..Thanks in advance

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Were you installing it with administrator privileges? (Right click on setup file and click on "Run as Administrator")

Comment: When I right click on the .msi file,I don't see "Run as administrator" option there..@ChiragRavindra

Comment: That option may be disabled by default. You can enable it by modifying your registry Or by running it through command line with admin privileges. Try this: https://www.howtogeek.com/178826/how-to-force-an-msi-package-to-install-using-administrator-mode/ OR http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-run-msi-file-as-administrator-from-command-prompt-in-windows/